# Fix for fatal error C1083

Tags: evc

We have a set of nightly builds that build of full suite of software using Embedded Visual C++ batch files.  There is probably a total of 30 builds that are done.  Every night at least one or two builds fail with something like the following error:

> c:\lc\trunk\server\can\svcangettracedrivelength.cpp(11) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'SH4Rel/CANWce.pch': Permission denied

It is never the same file or precompile header that fails and it is rarely the same executable.  As far as I know nothing else is happening on this build machine.

Does anyone have a fix to make our nightly builds run more reliably?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it all in the visual IDE; it will be easier to catch this way.

You sure you don't have multiple compiler instances working on several builds at once? One building a project/lib/whatever while another trying to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Does EVC 4.0 support macros? Maybe as a last resort you can have a macro that triggers the builds:)

I don't understand your last statement. Clearly the trouble is at compile time, not at run time.

Have you tried compiling without precompiled headers? What's the error then?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered apparently same issue - was seemingly caused by Microsoft Security Essentials.  I tried disabling it, and it immediately fixed the issue and it has not returned since.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking we do not see this error when running inside of the IDE (EVC++ 4.0).  We cannot run our nightly builds using the GUI, however.

As far as we know the build machine is idle while the nightly builds are running.